# std::thread Unhanded exception accessing this*

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a Timer class that calls a function passed to `create` and it loops and sleeps for what ever time given.
Problem im having is when trying to kill that timer from withen the passed function i get that exception at `pThis->Stop()`

I seem to get the same crash even if i access the global class object

Class:

```
class CTimer
{
public:
    CTimer()
        :_running(false)
    {}

    ~CTimer() {
        if (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            Stop();
        };
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        _running.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        if (_thread.joinable())
            _thread.join();
    }

    template <typename F, typename... A>
    void Start(int interval, F func, A&&... args)
    {
        if (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            Stop();

        _running.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        _thread = std::thread([this, interval, func, &args...]()
        {
            while (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            {
                func(this, std::forward<A>(args)...);

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
            }
        });
    }

    bool Running() const noexcept {
        return (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire) &&
            _thread.joinable());
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> _running;
    std::thread _thread;
};
```

Global:

```
CTimer Timer;
```

Thread:

```
void TimerThread(CTimer* pThis, HWND hwnd)
{
    // my code in side here
    // everything works fine till i try to stop within this thread


    // crash here
    pThis->Stop();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Timer.Start(2000, TimerThread, hwnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `join()` the thread from within itself—that's a problem.

See if you can stop the timer outside of the tick function. If you can't, then consider letting the tick function return a `bool` for whether it should keep going or not.

At any rate, the thread *should* always be joined, and always from a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

I took the code and removed `hwnd` - replacing with nullptr and found the following.

```
    if (_thread.joinable())
        _thread.join();
```

This code doesn't work in the thread function `TimerThread`, so when Stop is called, you get a deadlock exception thrown as explained [cppreference : thread join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

I think the fix should be to just set _running to false in the function.  But it is not clear what is really being required from the code.

### Other notes

Also the global timer destruction may occur too late - when globals are destroyed, this is as the C++ runtime is unloading, and a thread::join at this time would probably fail.

An interval would be more effective timing mechanism, where you measured the time before hand and then read it later.

The std::chrono features ways of reading clocks and getting timings.  [cppreference: chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
/* do some stuff */
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
```

Comment: there was a problem in my `Stop()` trying to join the thread, thanks, im a little confused on where your saying i should use `std::chrono` after i fixed my `Stop()` i started getting a crash the 2nd time starting the same timer again at `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a thread calling `join()` on itself is a guaranteed dead-lock - although one that should result in an exception.   You appear to be developing on Windows - so presumably using MSVC - You might want to check your library's standard compliance because until recently it wasn't.

There are several other really bad code-smells here:

#### Blocking in destructors

Currently the destructor for `CTimer` blocks for up to `interval` milliseconds.  This is a poor interface design as it is counter-intuitive.  You may very easily find yourself blocking the main thread for a long time, and furthermore there's a very real possibility of deadlock if `func()` blocks on resources - or attempts to destroy the `CTimer` object.  This is a code maintenance hazard stored up for the future.

#### Throwing exceptions in destructors

`std::thread::join()` can throw exceptions. This is a fast route to a `std::terminate` exception or undefined behaviour.

#### Capturing raw `this` pointers in async code

*just don't do it*

Whilst - I think - the life time of `CTimer` and the thread it spawns are currently aligned, this is a code-maintenance time-bomb.

Prefer instead to decouple the life-times of the thread and `CTimer` by capturing a `std::weak_ptr<CTimer>`:

```
class CTimer : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CTimer>
{
    .... 


    std::weak_ptr<CTimer> weakSelf{shared_from_this()};
    _thread = std::thread([weakSelf, interval, func, &args...]()
    {
```

And simply detaching the thread in the destructor

```
   ~CTimer() {
    if (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        _thread.detach();
    };
```

The loop in the timer thread becomes:

```
       while (1)
       {
            auto strongSelf = weakSelf.lock();
            if (!strongSelf);
                return;
            if (!strongSelf->_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
                return;

            func(this, std::forward<A>(args)...);

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
```

This has the added bonus of fixing the issue of blocking in destructor as well.   When the `CTimer` object is destroyed, the thread continues, eventually times-out and discovers that its creator no longer exists, and exits cleanly.

#### And inadvertently doing so with `func`

With this interface design it's all too easy for `func` to be bound to a non-static class member function.  Again, failing to control the relative life-times of objects.  A solution (at the caller) is to capture a `std::weak_ptr` in a lambda - or for you to change your interface to be less generic to enforce this.